# Using @JsonUnwrapped and having a custom Serializer (StdSerializer<T>)

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, jackson2, jackson-modules

I need to write a custom Serializer for one of my entities "Payment" and I have to implement it by extending `StdSerializer`:

```
class Payment {
}

class PaymentSerializer extends StdSerializer<Payment> {

    public PaymentSerializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public PaymentSerializer(Class<Payment> t) {
        super(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Payment value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        // some logics
    }

}
```

Since I use Spring, I register this Serializer so Spring could identify it:

```
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder serializersObjectMapperBuilder() {
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
    module.addSerializer(Payment.class, applicationContext.getBean(PaymentSerializer.class));
    return new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder().modules(module);
}
```

Now I have a controller that returns data back to the client and it uses this Serializer without any problem:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/payment")
class PaymentController {

    @GetMapping
    public List<Payment> getAll() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Payment());
    }

}
```

Since now, my Serializer works fine and everything is good.

The problem is with another entity "Order" which has Payment as a property with `@JsonUnwrapped`:

```
class Order {

    @JsonUnwrapped
    private Payment payment;

}
```

I need to unwrap the `Payment` inside the `Order` and I want to use **the same PaymentSerializer** but the problem is when I use this custom Serializer, the `@JsonUnwrapped` annotation will be ignored and the output will be something like this:

```
{
  "payment": {
    .....
  }
}
```

As I mentioned, I want to eliminate the "payment" field and unwrap it.
I know that for emulating `@JsonUnwrapped` for a custom Serializer I need to extend `UnwrappingBeanSerializer` class, but as I mentioned at first, I need the standard Serializer too.

Changing my entity models is not an option for me.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

I use `Spring Boot 2.1.3.RELEASE` which I believe uses `Jackson 2.9`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose the following way to solve issue:
We can compose two `StdSerializer` in single custom serializer.

```
@Component
class PaymentSerializer extends StdSerializer<Payment> {

    private final JsonSerializer<Payment> delegate = new UnwrappingPaymentSerializer(NameTransformer.NOP);

    public PaymentSerializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public PaymentSerializer(Class<Payment> t) {
        super(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Payment value, JsonGenerator generator, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        generator.writeStartObject();
        this.delegate.serialize(value, generator, provider);
        generator.writeEndObject();
    }

    @Override
    public JsonSerializer<Payment> unwrappingSerializer(final NameTransformer nameTransformer) {
        return new UnwrappingPaymentSerializer(nameTransformer);
    }

}
```

And unwrapping:

```
public class UnwrappingPaymentSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Payment> {

    private NameTransformer transformer;

    public UnwrappingPaymentSerializer(NameTransformer transformer) {
        this.transformer = transformer;
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Payment value, JsonGenerator generator, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        // some logics
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isUnwrappingSerializer() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

As result you have single serializer for serialization and unwrapping.
For more details see: https://michael-simons.github.io/simple-meetup/unwrapping-custom-jackson-serializer

Let me know if solution is not applicable, and I will try to propose other way depends on project requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, for the standard PaymentSerializer (and not the unwrapping one), I process some logic on the payment value and then delegate the serializing to a registered ObjectMapper: `myObjectMapper.getSerializerProviderInstance().defaultSerializeValue(value, gen);` now I want to the same thing for the  `UnwrappingPaymentSerializer ` too, is it possible to use an `ObjectMapper` for unwrapping serializing of an object? please check the below question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65741099/using-default-unwrapping-serializer-of-a-jackson-objectmapper

Comment: I think using ```ObjectMapper``` inside of ```Serializers``` is not good idea, because ```ObjectMapper``` is like registry for ```Serializers``` and ```Deserializers```, and that can produce infinity loop between Jackson component. About my solution: these two classes are interconnected and throught default ```JsonUnwrapped``` annotation will work, I tested, without extra configs, except your code ```module.addSerializer(Payment.class ...```, like you've already done.

Comment: since I've already registered the default `ObjectMapper`, there won't be any infinite loops. the question is how to access the default unwrapping serializer from an `ObjectMapper`, something like: `myObjectMapper...unwrappingSerializer(NameTransformer.NOP).serialize(value, gen, serializers)` how to call/access this default unwrappingSerializer from an  `ObjectMapper`

Comment: @DanielSmith I didn't find way to get ```unwrappingSerializer``` from ```ObjectMapper```, anyway in two solutions, you should create two classes, with two places of logic for serialization and unwrapping.