# Using default unwrapping serializer of a Jackson ObjectMapper

Tags: java, jackson, jackson2

I have a custom `JsonSerializer` and in the `serialize()` method I want to use the default serializer behavior of a registered `ObjectMapper`:

```
    class Serializer extends JsonSerializer<MyEntity> {

        private ObjectMapper myObjectMapper;

        @Override
        public void serialize(MyEntity value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
            
            // after processing some logic
            
            myObjectMapper.getSerializerProviderInstance().defaultSerializeValue(value, gen);

        }

    }
```

The code above works fine. now I want to do a similar thing but for `UnwrappingSerializer`, I mean I want to delegate the unwrappingSerializer to the registered `ObjectMapper` something like this:

```
    class UnwrappingSerializer extends JsonSerializer<MyEntity> {

        private ObjectMapper myObjectMapper;

        @Override
        public boolean isUnwrappingSerializer() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void serialize(MyEntity value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {

            // after processing some logic

            myObjectMapper.getDefaultUnwrappingSerializer().serialize(value); // how to do such a thing???

        }

    }
```

I'm not sure if Jackson supports such a thing or not. I know another option would be extending `UnwrappingBeanSerializer`, that's also fine, the only important thing for me is that I want to delegate the unwrapping serialization to an ObjectMapper and I don't want to do it manually. is there any way to do this?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

You can always create a new instance of ObjectMapper and use it within your serializer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but please read the question carefully. Accessing the ObjectMapper is not my concern, I want to use its unwrapping serializer, that's the problem.

Comment: This doesn't make a whole lot of sense. Try clarifying your issue.